# How to refresh UI in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am building a simple widget and I want to update it at on point.

```
class Example extends StatelessWidget {

  final bool isWhite;

  Example(this.isWhite)

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: isWhite ? Colors.white : Colors.black
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The RefreshIndicator class is useful to implement a cool pull down spinner as well. It essentially performs the same function as the answer below but looks nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a StatefulWidget widget and call

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => ExampleState();
}

class ExampleState extends State<Example> {
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0)).then(() {
        setState() {
        isWhite = !isWhite;
      });
    });
    return Container(
      color: isWhite ? Colors.white : Colors.black
    );
  }
}
```